# JQM Toggle Listview Item Theme

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a JQM listview where when the user clicks the item the theme toggles. I have gotten this far: http://jsfiddle.net/skNsF/6/. It almost works but the icon button on the right does not change.

How can I get the whole line to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to step through each child of the item and change the classes and themes. See solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/skNsF/10/.